# Enabling dates from datefield ExtJS with only to-be enabled dates given

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, datefield

I need to disable range of dates, where only the dates that needs to be enabled is available to me. I need to enable only those dates. I tried many ways like , disabledDates config of the 'datefield'. But, I was able to pass only the disabled dates. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance :-)

```
xtype: 'datefield',
anchor: '100%',
fieldLabel: 'Date',
itemId : 'sampleDateField',
name: 'date',
format: 'd M Y',
listeners : {
     expand : function(view) {
                 var date1 = '10 Apr 2015',
                     date2 = '15 Apr 2015',
                     date3 = '20 Apr 2015';
                 var array = [date1, date2, date3];
                // But I actually want to enable only these three dates. 
                // I dont have a config for it.
                 view.setDisabledDates(array);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you always know the accepted date? If it's the case, maybe you could use a comboBox?

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong, should be:

```
                 var date1 = '04/10/2015',
                     date2 = '04/15/2015',
                     date3 = '04/20/2015',
                     array = [date1, date2, date3]
```